# Google Drive Public Folder Dropbox

Tags: google-drive

Is it possible within a Google Drive domain to have a shared folder with read/write permissions but not delete permissions that would copy a file that is "shared" with that folder instead of it being an alias of the owners file?

If not, is there something in the Google Drive API that would allow for a PHP script that would activate once something is "shared" in a "shared folder" that would authenticate as a different user and copy a file from the shared folder to a private folder?

Answer (score 2):

I know that Google Drive has a "Copy to My Drive" option when you right click on a file someone shared with you but I don't think that can be done automatically from within the Drive webapp.

There exists a Drive API however that I think can easily be used in a Google Apps Script. I have no experience with Google Apps Script, but a little [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=manage%20shared%20drive%20files%20apps%20script) brought me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528467/google-apps-script-access-drive-sdk-api) on StackOverflow.

It appears to be fairly easy to manage Drive files from an App Script. I'm not sure if you can make Google Apps Scripts to do automation (like continuously checking Drive for new files), but I think it should, go and find out for yourself. If it can't do automation, you could launch it every time you discover new files in the shared folder.